# Parallelise heavy generator with I/O operation

Tags: python, async-await, multiprocessing, generator, python-asyncio

I have a project that I am considering making asynchronous due to its overhead cost and large runtime.
In this project I have a generator that generates about tens of millions of data

```
def generate_data():
   while True:
     yield data
     # break if condition fulfilled
```

The data generated is then written to a csv, row by row.

```
def _to_csv(data):
    temp = io.StringIO()
    csv_writer = csv.writer(
        temp, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in data:
        csv_writer.writerow([*row])
    return temp
```

The data is written as soon as it is gotten.
What would be the best approach to asynchronousness as I have tried `asyncio.as_completed` on the generator and it returns `async_generator not an iterator`
and `async for in data`(But my knowledge of this is that it doesn't parallelise, just allows for non-blocking operation). Would it be just enough without asynchronousness? What about multiprocessing?

Comment: I am not sure I am following your code. What is the *data* argument being passed to `_to_csv`? Is it `generate_data()` and if so you would be creating the complete CSV file as an in-memory string and I would then ask why you would do that? If you are passing something else, what is its relationship to `generate_data`?

Comment: The data being passed in is generate_data().
Reason for creating an in-memory string to store the csv is because I needed to a temp file I could pass around till it is no longer needed.